# Send & retrive data from Remote server through javascript

Tags: javascript

I created system that count my website visitor through javascript that's working fine But Now I want to show live Total Number of Visitor in my advertise which is in my other websites

So Please anybody can help me that how can I do this Or How can I Get data from my first website javascript data to my another website

I searched many thing in google but it do not answering my question

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://google.com <--- start with this site first.

Comment: Yes i search this problem in google majority it's showing fetching data from remote url like http://www.example.com/ip.php?ip=<data> and get data from here  but i do not  want fetch data from url but get from url

Comment: so? do you honestly think no one ever used js to retrieve data from a site?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all sites are served by the same host:

- send site visits to the server via AJAX or http POST (plenty of tutorials on how to do this
- store total visits in a database
- have your other site show this data (again Ajax or http post)

These are fairly trivial things to do and there is a ton of tutorials out there, I'd suggest w3schools as a starting point.

Comment: some other way without using database because My Website is static It does not have any database

Comment: If you want to store hits, you will need code on the server to store it. There is no way around it...

Comment: If you feel a db is overkill you could simply write to file but either method will involve a similar amount of code on the server. What do you mean by your website is static? I'm guessing right now your javascript hit counter doesn't persist between sessions (i.e. hitting refresh)